# How can I prove this equation: $(1+ \frac{1}{n})^n = 1+ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{k!}}1(1-\frac{1}{n})\cdot(1-\frac{2}{n})…(1-\frac{k-1}{n})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proving sequence equality using the binomial theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81887/proving-sequence-equality-using-the-binomial-theorem)

$(1+ \frac{1}{n})^n = 1+ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{k!}}\cdot1\cdot(1-\frac{1}{n})\cdot(1-\frac{2}{n})\cdot…\cdot(1-\frac{k-1}{n})$

This is how far I came using the binomial theorem:

$(1+ \frac{1}{n})^n = 1 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{k!}\cdot\frac{n!}{n^k\cdot(n-k)!}}$

I don't know how to rearrange that tail to be the same as in the original equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{n\,n\,n\cdots n}=\left(1-\frac0n\right)\,\left(1-\frac1n\right)\,\left(1-\frac2n\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{k-1}n\right).
$$

Comment: Oh thanks! :) I was so close.

Comment: I agree. $ $ $ $